# Mixed type in vector (rbind dataframe without typeconversion)

Tags: r, types, dataframe, rbind

In R a vector can not contain different types. Everything must e.g. be an integer or everything must be character etc. This gives me headaches sometimes. E.g. when I want to add a margin to a data.frame, and need some coloumns to be numeric and other to be characters.

Below a reproducible example:

```
# dummy data.frame
set.seed(42)
test <- data.frame("name"=sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE),
                   "val1" = runif(10,2,5),
                   "val2"=rnorm(10,10,5),
                   "Status"=sample(c("In progres", "Done"), 10, replace=TRUE),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# check that e.g. "val1" is indeed numeric
is.numeric(test$val1)
# TRUE
# create coloumn sums for my margin.
tmpSums <- colSums(test[,c(2:3)])
# Are the sums numeric?
is.numeric(tmpSums[1])
#TRUE
# So add the margin
test2 <- rbind(test, c("All", tmpSums, "Mixed"))
# is it numeric
is.numeric(test2$val1)
#FALSE
# DAMN. Because the vector `c("All", tmpSums, "Mixed")` contains strings
# the whole vector is forced to be a string. And when doing the rbind
# the orginal data.frame is forced to a new type also

# my current workaround is to convert back to numeric
# but this seems convoluted, back and forward.
valColoumns <- grepl("val", names(test2))
test2[,valColoumns] <- apply(test2[,valColoumns],2, function(x) as.numeric(x))
is.numeric(test2$val1)
# finally. It works.
```

there must be an easier / better way?

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh no? Reproducible example and OP's attempts to fix are present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `list` object in your `rbind`, like:

```
test2 <- rbind(test, c("All", unname(as.list(tmpSums)), "Mixed"))
```

Where the second argument to `rbind` is a list, removed of conflicting names that will cause `rbind` to fail:

```
c("All", unname(as.list(tmpSums)), "Mixed")
#[[1]]
#[1] "All"
# 
#[[2]]
#[1] 37.70092
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 91.82716
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "Mixed"
```

Comment: Not really worth a separate answer, but `rbind` for `data.table`s has a `use.names` argument which would allow you to skip `unname`. Matter of taste.

Comment: thanks. I did find the unname bit myself - but never thought to use a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), get the `sum` of the numeric columns using `lapply`, concatenate (`c`) with the values that should represent for other columns, place it in a `list` and use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rAll <-  setDT(test)[, c(name="All", lapply(.SD, sum), 
              Status="Mixed"), .SDcols= val1:val2]
rbindlist(list(test, rAll))
```

---

If we need to make it a bit more automatic,

```
i1 <- sapply(test, is.numeric)
v1 <- setNames(list("All", "Mixed"), setdiff(names(test),
                      names(test)[i1]))
rAll <-  setDT(test)[, c(v1, lapply(.SD, sum)), 
                 .SDcols=i1][, names(test), with=FALSE]
rbindlist(list(test, rAll))
```

Comment: Sweet. This is a great answer. I have to mark 'thelatemail' answer as accepted because it is a bit closer (using data.frame) - but this is arguable an answer i'll use just as much - and maybe learned more from.

Comment: @Andreas  Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, you should mark thelatemail's answer as it is a great one with the original idea.